# start_command() missing 1 positional argument?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, error-handling, typeerror

I've been debugging a program that gets files from a user specified directory, converts them, and creates a new file in another user specified directory. I am now getting an error that I cannot seem to figure out. The `start_command` function gets the `directory` from the `e1` entry box. My `browse` functions work perfectly to get the directory path and place it in `e1`. I use `self.directory.get()` to grab the path and send it along to the different functions within `start_command()`. I cannot see where I am missing something here. Any insight would be helpful.

The error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/root/Desktop/I.T.E.D./ITED.py", line 108, in <lambda>
    b1 = Button(self, text='Start', width=12, command=lambda: start_command(self.excel_file.get(), self.directory.get()))
TypeError: start_command() missing 1 required positional argument: 'directory'
```

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import hashlib
import converter
import time
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import filedialog


class ITED(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F,geometry in zip((StartPage, PageOne), ('250x100', '550x250')):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = (frame, geometry)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        print(self.frames)

        self.show_frame("StartPage")


    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame, geometry = self.frames[page_name]
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.geometry(geometry)
        frame.tkraise()


    def quit(self):
        self.app.destroy()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        l1 = Label(self, text='Please enter key:')
        l1.pack(side=TOP, expand=True)

        self.password = StringVar()
        e3 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.password)
        e3.pack(side=TOP, expand=True)

        b6 = Button(self, text='Validate', width=12, command=lambda: self.admin(self.password.get()))
        b6.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True)
        b7 = Button(self, text='Close', width=12, command=quit)
        b7.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True)


    def admin(self, password):
        admin_key = '72b302bf297a228a75730123efef7c41'
        hash_object = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
        key = hash_object.hexdigest()

        if key == admin_key:
            print('Success...')
            self.destroy()
            self.controller.show_frame("PageOne")

        else:
            print('Permission Denied...')
            print(key)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        l2 = Label(text='Use the browse buttons to select the proper folder.')
        l2.pack(side=TOP)
        l3 = Label(text='PDF Directory: The location of the folder containing the PDFs you wish to convert')
        l3.pack(side=TOP)
        l4 = Label(text='Excel Directory: The location you wish to create the Excel file within')
        l4.pack(side=TOP)
        instructions1 = Label(self, text='PDF Directory: ')
        instructions1.pack()
        self.directory = StringVar()
        e1 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.directory)
        e1.pack()
        b3 = Button(self, text='Browse', width=8, command=lambda: browsepath())
        b3.pack()
        instructions2 = Label(self, text='Excel Directory: ')
        instructions2.pack()
        self.excel_file = StringVar()
        e2 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.excel_file)
        e2.pack()
        b4 = Button(self, text='Browse', width=8, command=lambda: browsespd())
        b4.pack()

        progress = Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=500, mode='determinate')
        progress.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        b1 = Button(self, text='Start', width=12, command=lambda: self.start_command(self.excel_file.get(), self.directory.get()))
        b1.pack(side=LEFT)
        b2 = Button(self, text='Close', width=12, command=quit)
        b2.pack(side=RIGHT)




        def start_command(self, excel_file, directory):
            converter.create_json(directory)
            converter.create_xlsx(excel_file, directory)
            converter.check_if_existing(directory)
            converter.convert(new_list, directory)


        def browsepath():
            foldername = filedialog.askdirectory()
            e1.delete(0, END)
            e1.insert(END, foldername)


        def browsespd():
            filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
            e2.delete(0, END)
            e2.insert(END, filename)


        def bar():
            progress['value'] = 20
            self.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1)

            progress['value'] = 40
            self.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1)

            progress['value'] = 50
            self.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1)

            progress['value'] = 60
            self.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1)

            progress['value'] = 80
            self.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1)
            progress['value'] = 100


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ITED()
    app.title("I.T.E.D. Converter")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Without trying the code, I guess that ``start_command`` needs a ``self`` parameter as first argument which at the moment in your case is ``self.excel_file.get()`` OR use  ``self.start_command``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        l2 = Label(text='Use the browse buttons to select the proper folder.')
        l2.pack(side=TOP)
        l3 = Label(text='PDF Directory: The location of the folder containing the PDFs you wish to convert')
        l3.pack(side=TOP)
        l4 = Label(text='Excel Directory: The location you wish to create the Excel file within')
        l4.pack(side=TOP)
        instructions1 = Label(self, text='PDF Directory: ')
        instructions1.pack()
        self.directory = StringVar()
        e1 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.directory)
        e1.pack()
        b3 = Button(self, text='Browse', width=8, command=lambda: browsepath())
        b3.pack()
        instructions2 = Label(self, text='Excel Directory: ')
        instructions2.pack()
        self.excel_file = StringVar()
        e2 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.excel_file)
        e2.pack()
        b4 = Button(self, text='Browse', width=8, command=lambda: browsespd())
        b4.pack()

        progress = Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=500, mode='determinate')
        progress.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        b1 = Button(self, text='Start', width=12, command=lambda: self.start_command(self.excel_file.get(), self.directory.get()))
        b1.pack(side=LEFT)
        b2 = Button(self, text='Close', width=12, command=quit)
        b2.pack(side=RIGHT)




    def start_command(self, excel_file, directory):
        converter.create_json(directory)
        converter.create_xlsx(excel_file, directory)
        converter.check_if_existing(directory)
        converter.convert(new_list, directory)


    def browsepath(self):
        foldername = filedialog.askdirectory()
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e1.insert(END, foldername)


    def browsespd(self):
        filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
        e2.delete(0, END)
        e2.insert(END, filename)
```

with further tweaks, can't develop further without things like `Progressbar` and `convertor`.

What I've done is I've made `start_command`, `browsepath` and `browsespd` local methods of `PageOne` by unidenting them which would mean that you wouldn't need to pass them `self` argument, but you now have to call them by using something like `self.start_command` or `pageOne_object.start_command`.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to OOP and trying to learn so every little problem teaches me something. However, after making the adjustment from `start_command(self.excel_file.get(), self.directory.get()))` to `self.start_command(self.excel_file.get(), self.directory.get()))` I now am getting an AttributeError: 'PageOne' object has no attribute 'start_command'. I'm updating the code section to include the entire frontend code. Everything was working fine until I started to expand the project to take in user specified paths and multiple tkinter windows.

Comment: Unindent everything from `def start_command` down to `e2.insert...`

Comment: Well then, I'm not sure how that happened, but I hadn't noticed everything got moved. Thanks!